# Como puedo hacer un correlativo de una factura/boleta

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, script

queridos developers.
Quisiera que me ayudaran en hacer una consulta en sql server para poder un correlativo de una factura, boleta, nota de crédito y nota de débito. Estoy buscando ejemplos de como poder crear una pero no logro encontrar información. Por favor me podrían ayudar y explicarme su script para poder entenderlo, estoy aprendiendo solo y estoy haciendo un sistema propio para agregarlo a mi portafolio. Se los agradecería mucho. Lo haré en el lenguaje de C#

```
create table Correlativo
(
IdCorrelativo INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Nombre VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '',
Prefijo VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
Subfijo VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '',
NCorrelativo BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
Ancho INT DEFAULT 0,
Estado CHAR(1)
)
go

Insert into Correlativo values ('Pedidos', 'P19', 'PE', 0, 8, 1)
go
Insert into Correlativo values ('Facturas', 'FA01', '', 0, 4, 1)
go
Insert into Correlativo values ('Boletas', 'BA01', '', 0, 8, 1)
go
```

Comment: A que te refieres con correlativo?

Comment: Hola, me refiero a que al momento de que se cree una factura o boleta, comiencen a generar su correlativo por la orden del registro, por ejemplo: la primera factura será F001-0000001, la que le sigue F001-0000002 y así sucesivamente. El usuario al registrar un nuevo pedido tiene que tener bien el correlativo

Comment: Tal cual lo creaste sera incremental, y el usuario no deberia reservar un numero de factura, hasta darle click al finalizar ese proceso, porque si reserva y nunca termina el tramite vas a tener salteado los numeros y eso esta mal.

Comment: Claro, estoy buscando como hacer eso, que al momento de que finalice recién bote el resultado final. Ando viendo como hacerlo en un procedimiento almacenado, que me capture y me identifique si el pedido de compra es factura o boleta

Comment: Ya entendi, si es boleta quieres que el numero sea correlativo en todas las boletas y no lo encuentres salteado, y lo mismo con factura o Pedidos. Deberias realizar una consulta con el tipo que desee y obtienes su numero mayor y le sumas 1, pero creo que seria mas ordenado si separas en tablas, ya que estas hablando de cosas diferentes y no tener que hacer una consulta cada vez que agregas algo y evitas usar cpu.

Comment: Mnnn quisiera algo dinámico, todo en una sola tabla, ya que así puedo sacar una consulta como un select y where para que así nada mas me busque lo que quiero en una sola tabla y no tener muchas. Ando buscando info de ejemplos pero aún no encuentro como hacerlo, ya llevo 2 días así y esto de aprender solo es un poco complicado

Comment: Programar todo reducido no hace que sea mas facil tu codigo o funcione mas rapido, a veces debes escribir un poco mas para que la mantencion del codigo sea mas rapida, mas facil de leer y funcione mas rapido el software, creo que es un consejo simple que te doy y si eres nuevo deberias seguir. Despues votaran a favor el comentario si estoy en lo correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Para recuperar el valor actual y sumarle uno, generando el siguiente debes primero recuperarlo usando algo como ser

```
SELECT NCorrelativo FROM Correlativo WHERE Nombre = 'Facturas'
```

ya que solo tendras un unico registro para llevar el registro de facturas.

Desde el codigo podria ser algo como esto

```
public int UltimoNro(string tipo)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT NCorrelativo FROM Correlativo WHERE Nombre = @tipo";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(..))
    {
        conn.Open();
        
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", tipo);
        
        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

Nota: Si quieres otro tipo de documento solo cambias el WHERE, por eso el parametro

Cuando generes el nuevo documento le sumaras 1 al que obtienes y al final deberas realizar un UPDATE del registro asi queda acentada la operacion

```
UPDATE NCorrelativo = NCorrelativo + 1 WHERE Nombre = 'Facturas'
```

asi la proxima consulta obtendra el valor actualizado

Comment: Eh visto que ayudas mucho por el foro de Microsoft y por aquí, lo probaré, muchas gracias Leandro, en serio, esto de aprender solo a veces es muy duro y esto me ayuda mucho a seguir y no quedarme estancado en el problema.